# reshape data in plsql

Tags: plsql, pivot-table, reshape

I write a query which returns result like this :

[image]

but I should reshape result like below :
[image: ![enter image description here]

in fact, what I want is to track date and doc_no and qty for specific act_desc_, Can someone help me to rewrite query reshape in PL SQL? I would appreciate it if somebody can help me.

Comment: PL/SQL specifically, or just a query?

Comment: SQL is also very similar, SQL or PLSQL is ok

Comment: PL/SQL is a programming language. I think you might mean Oracle SQL, which is a query language.

Comment: just a query is ok

Comment: Please provide sample data script.

Comment: Please provide with table definition & sample data as ascii in a code block, your SQL, and explain the logic you want applied. Kindly see [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952). This post also has a link to a tool to create tables as ascii. Can there only be two different task for any act_desc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you've posted an image, i'll give you an example of how you can do it using some quick mock data, with SQL:

```
select ACT_DESC, MAX(EXCAVATION_QTY) as EXCAVATION_QTY, MAX(FORM_WORK_COMPLETION_QTY) as FORM_WORK_COMPLETION_QTY
from (
    select QTY, ACT_DESC, TASK, 
        CASE WHEN TASK = 'EXCAVATION' THEN QTY ELSE NULL END as EXCAVATION_QTY,
        CASE WHEN TASK = 'Form Work Completion' THEN QTY ELSE NULL END as FORM_WORK_COMPLETION_QTY
    FROM
    (
    select 1 as QTY, 'a' as ACT_DESC, 'Excavation' as TASK
    UNION ALL
    select 2 as QTY, 'a' as ACT_DESC, 'Form Work Completion' as TASK
    UNION ALL
    select 11 as QTY, 'b' as ACT_DESC, 'Excavation' as TASK
    UNION ALL
    select 22 as QTY, 'b' as ACT_DESC, 'Form Work Completion' as TASK
    ) as t
) t1
GROUP BY ACT_DESC
```

It takes:
[image]

and converts it into:
[image]

Comment: it worked very well, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

/*
There are numerous complex queries that can be used, but here is a quick
and simple method that creates a base table first, then populates it after.
*/
--Step 1: Create empty base table with columns of the correct data type

```
CREATE TABLE BASE_TABLE AS 
(
 SELECT
  ACT_DESC_,

  QTY AS EXCAVATION_QTY,
  APP_DATE AS EXCAVATION_APP_DATE,
  DOC_NO AS EXCAVATION_DOC_NO,

  QTY AS FORM_WORK_COMP_QTY,
  APP_DATE AS FORM_WORK_COMP_APP_DATE,
  DOC_NO AS FORM_WORK_COMP_DOC_NO,

 FROM
  SOURCE_TABLE --this is the original table, or the table from the first image
 WHERE 0=1 --this clause condition is used to create an empty table
);
```

--Step 2: Insert into base table the unique ACT_DESC_ values

```
INSERT INTO BASE_TABLE
(
 SELECT DISTINCT
  ACT_DESC_
 FROM
  SOURCE_TABLE
);
```

--Using Merge statements
--Step 3: Update base table based on TASK_ = 'Excavation'

```
MERGE INTO BASE_TABLE TGT --Alias TGT short for TarGeT table
USING
 (
  SELECT * FROM SOURCE_TABLE
  WHERE TASK_ = 'Excavaion'
 ) SRC --Alias SRC short for SouRCe table
ON ( TGT.ACT_DESC_ = SRC.ACT_DESC_ )
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
SET 
  TGT.EXCAVATION_QTY = SRC.QTY
  TGT.EXCAVATION_APP_DATE = SRC.APP_DATE
  TGT.EXCAVATION_DOC_NO = SRC.DOC_NO;
```

--Step 4: Update base table based on TASK_ = 'Form Work Completion'

```
MERGE INTO BASE_TABLE TGT --Alias TGT short for TarGeT table
USING
 (
  SELECT * FROM SOURCE_TABLE
  WHERE TASK_ = 'Form Work Completion'
 ) SRC --Alias SRC short for SouRCe table
ON ( TGT.ACT_DESC_ = SRC.ACT_DESC_ )
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
SET 
  TGT.FORM_WORK_COMP_QTY = SRC.QTY
  TGT.FORM_WORK_COMP_APP_DATE = SRC.APP_DATE
  TGT.FORM_WORK_COMP_DOC_NO = SRC.DOC_NO;
```

Comment: thank you for the answer but I can't create a new table in the database